# Postgresql Query for customers who are not active from last 2 year

Tags: postgresql

I want to find the customers who are not coming in the parlour  for treatment from the last 2 year.

### Customer table has the details in customer table as below

Customer no, Customer Name,Address, DateofRegistration

1. 111, Ram, Address1, 11-Aug-2013
2. 112, Vivek, Address2, 12-Aug-2013
3. 113, Rao, Addrees3, 20-Sept-2014
4. 114, Smita, Address4, 21-Sept-2014

### Treatment table has the following details

Customer no, ,Treatment name,Treatment date

- 111, treatment1, 11-Aug-2013
- 111, treatment2,  10-Sep-2014
- 111,treatment1  ,5-Jan- 2015
- 112, treatment 1  ,12-Aug-2013
- 112, treatment 2, 6-Jan-2015
- 113, treatment1, 20-sept-2014
- 113, treatment 1, 5-feb-2016
- 113, treatment 1, 11-Mar-2017
- 114, treatment 1, 21-sept-2014
- 114, treatment 2, 15-dec-2015
- 115, treatment 1, 1- Jul -2017

When we look at the treatment table , customer no 111,112 have no records from the last 2 year. That is they are not visited the parlour for the treatment. So I want to find out those customer who don't have records from the last 2 year.
 As i am new to postgres, I am not getting any clue how to build this query. Please guide me.

Comment: Please detail the structure of your tables and how "not coming to the parlor for the last 2 years" is represented in your data. Also, we would be more inclined to help you if you show us what you tried so far and why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Suppose Treatment Date column name is "treatment_date" and its type is Date, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM Treatment
WHERE
DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', treatment_date) > 2
```

Comment: The above query is giving wrong results .The records 113 and 114 are also showing and which is having latest entry on 2017 as well. So i think we need to find the max(treatment_date) first then check the difference

Comment: Try this .... SELECT DISTINCT ON (customer_no) * FROM Treatment
WHERE
DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', treatment_date) > 2
ORDER BY treatment_date DESC

Comment: I am able to make a query like this   ..........                                                          SELECT tr.custmerno, cr.firstname, cr.lastname   from Treatment tr
join customer cr on cr.custmerno = tr.custmerno group by 1,2,3 having (max("treatmentdate"):: date) < '2015-01-01'   order by tr.custmerno  .    Now it will lists all the customer who are not coming after 2015 But i wanted to filter those records for particualr year as well.